# Disable Delete in Asp.Net Dynamic Data for One Table but Allow Insert

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic-data

Hi I have a site where I use a User Table. I want to be able to add users but not delete them - I need to update a filed in the database that said Is Deleted - Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an custom form for every Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like Linq to SQL or Entity Framework (or other ORM), and create a CRUD repository (Create, Read, Update, Delete).  But the method for the "D" will actually be an update method that updates the `isDeleted` field.

Here's an example of my CRUD repository (with a service layer as well).
http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2010/07/04/MVC2-Separating-Concerns-with-Service-and-Repository-Layers.aspx

**Example:**

```
Public Class UserRepository : Implements IUserRepository 
    Private dc As MyDatabaseDataContext 
    Public Sub New() 
        dc = New MyDatabaseDataContext 
    End Sub 

    ''# note, this adds a user based on an OpenID - might not be what you're looking for
    Public Sub AddUser(ByVal openid As OpenID) Implements IUserRepository.AddUser 
        Dim user As New User 
        user.MemberSince = DateTime.Now 
        openid.User = user 

        dc.OpenIDs.InsertOnSubmit(openid) 
    End Sub 

    ''# This gets users as Queryable so that we can defer the query till the end.
    Public Function GetUsers() As IQueryable(Of User) Implements IUserRepository.GetUsers 
        Dim users = (From u In dc.Users 
                    Select u) 
        Return users.AsQueryable 
    End Function 

    ''# Here's the magic function that you're looking for. DELETE is actually an UPDATE.
    Public Sub DeleteUser(ByVal user as User) Implements IUserRepository.DeleteUser
        Dim _user = (From u In dc.Users 
            Where u.ID = user.ID 
            Select u).Single 

        _user.isDeleted = True
    End Sub


    ''# Basic Update Method
    Public Sub UpdateUser(ByVal user As User) Implements IUserRepository.UpdateUser 
        Dim _user = (From u In dc.Users 
            Where u.ID = user.ID 
            Select u).Single 

        With _user 
            .About = user.About 
            .BirthDate = user.BirthDate 
            .Email = user.Email 
            .isClosed = user.isClosed 
            .isProfileComplete = user.isProfileComplete 
            .RegionID = user.RegionID 
            .Reputation = user.Reputation 
            .UserName = user.UserName 
            .WebSite = user.WebSite 
        End With 

    End Sub 

    ''# Make sure to call SubmitChanges
    Public Sub SubmitChanges() Implements IUserRepository.SubmitChanges 
        dc.SubmitChanges() 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: How do I set that the delete function in Dynamic Data use my code?

Comment: Dynamic Data is still using Linq To SQL.  Go into the code behind of the Edit template and post the edit code (just edit your existing question).  I don't use Dynamic Data (I've chosen MVC instead), but the principles will be the same.